# Issue with Asynctask in Android MySQL server request class

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I have been following this tutorial about registering a user with android app through PHP and mysql and I have a problem with the AsyncTask class. Here is the code:

```
public class ServerRequests extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;
    ServerRequests(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        String REG_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/ibumobile/register.php";
        String LOGIN_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/ibumobile/login.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if(method.equals("register")) {
            String email = params[1];
            String studentID = params[2];
            String password = params[3];
            try {

                URL url = new URL(REG_URL);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //Output to the server
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("studentID", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(studentID, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();

                //Input from the server
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Registration successful...";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The error states that `doInBackground()` uses incompatible return type, and I totally understand, but I am unable to fix it.

And here is the registration activity code if you might need it:

```
public class Register extends Activity {

    EditText email, studentID, password, repPassword;
    String regEmail, regStudentID, regPassword, regRepPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Find Text Form by id
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regEmail);
        studentID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regStudentID);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPassword);
        repPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regRepPassword);


        //startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }

    public void registerUser(View view) {

        //Convert text form input to string
        regEmail = email.getText().toString();
        regStudentID = studentID.getText().toString();
        regPassword = password.getText().toString();
        regRepPassword = repPassword.getText().toString();

        String method = "register";
        ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
        serverRequests.execute(method, regEmail, regStudentID, regPassword, regRepPassword);
        finish();

    }



}
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: @SebastianWalla It actually detects this line as the problem: `return "Registration successful...";`

Comment: Please have a look at my answer @Bill Hick's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to return a string, but the returntype you specified in the method head is `Void`.

So changing it to `String` would fix your error.

And as a general thing: From the aspect of security you should not send credentials as the passwort via an insecure connection such as http. It is very easy to create a more secure https connection in android. If you want more information regarding that, just comment it.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, it just created additional errors. BTW followed a tutorial, it worked for the guy.

Comment: @BillHicks could you add the link?

Comment: As I told you, he is also changing at minute 16:27 the return type of the method to `String`. https://youtu.be/cOsZHuu8Qog?t=16m27s

Comment: Woo, totally missed it, I feel so stupid, thanks anyway, I appreciate it.

Comment: @BillHicks No problem, I`m happy that I could help you. Everybody misses something. Please remember to accept answers, that helped you, so that other users with your problem can see, what fixed your problem.